# Have diagonalization, need orthogonal diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software

I have a symmetric matrix $A$ and I want to find an orthogonal diagonalization of $A$, i.e, matrices $B$ and $D$ such that:

$$ A = B D B^{-1}$$

and $D$ is diagonal and $B^{-1} = B^T$.

I use a math software <sub>(sympy)</sub> that lets my diagonalize any matrix, i.e, it lets me find $C$ and $D$ such that:

$$ A = C D C^{-1}$$

and $D$ is diagonal, but usually $C^{-1}\neq C^T$.

Can I use this function to find an orthogonal diagonalization of a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt process doesn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *sympy* and so I don't know whether or in which form it has a diagonalization by an explicite SVD-decomposition. So here a somehow "pseudocode" how to arrive at that.

---

If $B$ is *orthogonal*, then $B^{-1}=B^\tau$ . Being orthogonal means $B$ is a *rotation-matrix*. So if you do a rotation on the rows and the same rotation, but transposed, on the columns then you arrive at a diagonal matrix $D$ and a suitable matrix $B$ .

I have implemented such a procedure as standard-diagonalization procedure for symmetric matrices (main target: correlation-matrices in my statistics-projects) in the matrix-language-program "MatMate". Here, when we have a symmetric matrix we can simply write

```
A = randomn(4,4)
A = A * A'  // A is now a symmetric matrix
// ---------------------------
B = gettrans(A,"pca")    // rotating a symmetrix matrix to PC-position
                         // getting back the transformation-/rotation matrix
B_I = inv(B)
D = B_I * A * B 
// check:
CHK = B * D * B_1  - A   // to be zero if diagonalization ok
CHK = B_I - B'            // to be zero if B = B^T
```

$$  \text{ A } = \small \left[\begin{array} {rrrr} 
  7.2591& -3.5564& -0.5114&  0.0493\\
 -3.5564&  3.6224& -2.2029& -0.1632\\
 -0.5114& -2.2029&  3.3816& -0.3112\\
  0.0493& -0.1632& -0.3112&  1.7369
 \end{array} \right] $$

---

$$  \text{ B }=\small  \left[\begin{array} {rrrr} 
  0.8280&  0.3880&  0.0995&  0.3923\\
 -0.5461&  0.3984&  0.1362&  0.7242\\
  0.1263& -0.8280&  0.0273&  0.5456\\
  0.0116&  0.0713& -0.9853&  0.1548
 \end{array}\right]
$$

$$ \text{ D } \small = \left[ \begin{array} {rrrr} 
  9.5274&  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000\\
  0.0000&  4.7079&  0.0000&  0.0000\\
  0.0000&  0.0000&  1.7631&  0.0000\\
  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0016
 \end{array} \right] $$

$$  \text{ B}^{-1} = \small \left[ \begin{array} {rrrr} 
  0.8280& -0.5461&  0.1263&  0.0116\\
  0.3880&  0.3984& -0.8280&  0.0713\\
  0.0995&  0.1362&  0.0273& -0.9853\\
  0.3923&  0.7242&  0.5456&  0.1548
 \end{array} \right]
 $$

If you can't reingeneer the `gettrans(B,"pca")`-procedure (it is also a SVD-decomposition) then a simpler (?) method is the rotation to triangular shape, but this must then be iterated:

```
D=A
B=einh(4)   \\ initialize the iteratively converging rotation-process
\\ ----------------------
t = gettrans(D,"drei")    // iterate this three steps until convergence
B=B * t                   //
D = t' * D' * t           //  
\\ ----------------------
B_I = inv(B)
```

This routine gave the same results to 10 decimal digits precision by ca 20 iterations.